# react-router and pretty URLs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, single-page-application, react-router-redux

What is the best way to use `react-router` with pretty URLs?
All URLs are stored in DB (total amount about `400,000`).
When I follow link I need to resolve component for rendering from the server by `AJAX` request and render it.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Implement dynamic routing in routes.js for generated menu items in sidebar in universal react redux boilerplate by erikras](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35764510/how-to-implement-dynamic-routing-in-routes-js-for-generated-menu-items-in-sideba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer for the question. With `react-router` you could dynamically resolve component with `getComponent` method of `Route`.
For example:

```
import ProductPage from '...'
import CategoryPage from '...'

const MAP_PAGE_TYPE_TO_COMPONENT = {
    'productPage': ProductPage,
    'categoryPage': CategoryPage

};

....

const getComponent = (location, callback) => {
  requestToServer(location.pathname)
    .then(function(response){
      const Component = MAP_PAGE_TYPE_TO_COMPONENT[response.pageType];
      callback(null, <Component items = { response.items } />);
     })
    .catch(callback)
};

....

<Route 
  path='*'
  getComponent = { getComponent }
/>
```

You should call `callback` function with `null` as first parameter if there is no error, and `<Component />` as second parameter.

Comment: is there any answer for this problem in Reactjs and axios request? intead of AJAX? ,i have the same problem and i want to make my react dynamic URL , readable

Comment: You can create an API for getting the information about URL and use it with axios as well: `axios.request({url: '/you-api-endpoint'}).then(/* rest code */)`

Answer (score 2):

React router can take dynamic values which can be database driven.

For example, if you have a database of products, you can have a Link like this:

```
<Link to="/products/1234/product_name">Product</Link>
```

And your component would be defined like this:

```
<Route path="/products/:id/:url_title" component={Products} />
```

Comment: The pathnames in your example have defined structure. I said about pathnames like this:
`/buy-iphone7-red` or `/buy-apple-macbook-retina-13`.

Comment: I see. In which case you could probably go with something like `<Route path="/:url_title" component={Post} />`

Comment: I have `400,000` `URLs` in my `DB`. It's not a good idea. I posted an answer which resolves this issue. Thanks!