# dynamic routing in react js, component name from a string cannot be assigned in route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently trying to learn reactjs, and i came across on router-react-dom, i was trying to create a dynamic router, and found this solution [How to Implement dynamic routing in routes.js for generated menu items in sidebar in universal react redux boilerplate by erikras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35764510/how-to-implement-dynamic-routing-in-routes-js-for-generated-menu-items-in-sideba) Solution Option 2 but i could not make it work on my end.

Here is my Main.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Link, Redirect, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './Home'
import Inbox from './Inbox'
import Trash from './Trash'
import Order from './Order'
import Protected from './Protected'
import Login from './Login'
import Forums from './Forums'
import NoMatch from './NoMatch'
import Promos from './Promos'

import SiteRoutes from './Nav'

const Main = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch> 
      {SiteRoutes.public.map(route => 
          <Route
            key={route.index}
            path={route.path}
            exact={route.exact}
            component={route.main}
          />
        )}

    </Switch>
  </main>
)
export default Main;
```

And here is my Nav.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Data  = {
  public :[
        {
          path: "/",
          exact: true,
          main: 'Home'
        },
        {
          path: "/inbox",
          main: 'Inbox'
        },
        {
          path: "/trash",
          main: 'Trash'
        },
        {
          path: "/order/:value",
          main: 'Order'
        },
        {
          path: "/login",
          main: 'Login'
        },
        {
          path: "/forums",
          main: 'Forums'
        },
        {
          path: "/promos",
          main: 'Promos'
        }
      ]
};

export default Data;
```

I am trying to map and create a dynamic routes base from the Nav.js, but my problem is on the part of creating the Route on the `component={route.main}`, which assigns the `route.main` string value from Nav.js seems to not work in my situation. I followed what was on the link i mentioned above.

When i am clicking the link, console error is 
`index.js:2178 Warning: <Home /> is using uppercase HTML. Always use lowercase HTML tags in React.` i guess because it was a string and wont call the component, but on link i mentioned above seems to work on their end. I am wondering is there something missing in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string, when passed to `React.createElement`, creates a *DOM element*, not a custom component, which are usually only lowercase, hence the warning. Instead, I'd recommend just storing the component classes in `Nav.js` itself:

```
import Home from './Home'
import Inbox from './Inbox'
import Trash from './Trash'
import Order from './Order'
import Protected from './Protected'
import Login from './Login'
import Forums from './Forums'
import NoMatch from './NoMatch'
import Promos from './Promos'

const Data = {
  public: [
    {
      path: "/",
      exact: true,
      main: Home
    },
    …
  ]
}
```

So when React Router creates the component internally, it will create the element from a component class, not a string.

Comment: Thanks @Li357, i will get back to you tomorrow and will try this, so you mean the link that i mention on the option 2 solution will not work?

Comment: @Efx The second solution is wrong. As I mentioned in my answer, you can't pass a string, but you need a component class.

Comment: Thanks @Li357, will be using your approach then.